# Filter Date field records with null values in kafka (AIVEN) connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a small challenge that I can't get any further with.

I have a Kafka Aiven Sink Connector that basically works great.
Now it happens from time to time that a date field contains zero. I would like to sort out these values.

Unfortunately,

```
behavior.on.null.values
```

does not work because the record itself is not null but only a field within the record.

I have also tried to filter with Connect Transforms,
like:

```
"transforms.filterEvent.filter.condition": "$[?(@.field == null)]"
```

but unfortunately this plugin does not support Date fields, only String & Int.

Is it possible to transform the field for the check?

Do you have any idea how this could be done?